# view database data that was created today by a specific user

Tags: laravel, date, controller, userid

I'm creating a `foodlog` and I want a user to be able to search through the days and view food that was only logged that day.
For example, on the page for today's date I only want to see all the food items that I logged for today.

I have my table getting all data from that specific user from all dates, but how do I narrow it down to just today?

**FoodlogController.php**

```
public function show() {

    $userId = Auth::user()->id;

    $posts = Post::where('user_id', $userId)->get();


    return view('foodlog', compact('posts'));

}
```

**This is what my table looks like**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have the default timestamps on, which add `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. If that's not the case, and you log time of creation with a different column, just replace the `created_at` with it.

Laravel comes with a hand package for dealing with dates - [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), which can be used by importing it from `Carbon\Carbon` namespace.

And Laravel's query builder has a method [whereDate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) (scroll to "whereDate"), which can be used exactly for this.

Combining these 2, you could do this:

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $userId)->whereDate('created_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today())->get();
```

This will get the posts that were created today.

**However**

I would strongly recommend you create a [`hasMany` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) (user `hasMany` posts and inversely a post `belongsTo` a user), which would enable to use relationships and do something like this:

```
$posts = $user->posts()->whereDate('created_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today())->get();
```

And many more things, the Laravel way.